# In KITTI Dataset, which sequence that start with initial velocity of 0?

Tags: dataset, ros, kitti

I want to use [KITTI dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/index.php) too do SLAM (Simultaneous Localization And Mapping) in [Google Cartographer in ROS](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I need set of sequence of KITTI (from [Raw](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php) or [Odometry](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php) dataset) which the vehicle's initial velocity in that sequence is 0. Which sequence that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which one, but the data set comes with a txt file which has a ground truth solution that can tell you the velocity at the first frame.